# raw cannot be resolved or is not a field error (Eclipse/Android/Java)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

For some odd reason I'm getting this error: `raw cannot be resolved or is not a field`

I'm trying to do the following

```
   MediaPlayer click = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button_click.mp3);
```

in my onCreate method.

I've checked the folder & mp3 file, and it's `<project-name>/raw/button_click.mp3`. I've tried:

- Cleaning up my project
- Restarting Eclipse
- Making it R.raw.button_click
- Checking if everything's lowercased & spelled correctly

Help, please!

Comment: Raw might be used as a keyword in eclipse or android

Comment: No , it was suppose to be in <project-name>/res/raw/.mp3

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Shouldn't it be in projectname/res/raw, instead of projectname/raw?

Comment: I'm glad to help, John. If you could mark my answer as accepted, that would be awesome. ;) Thanks!